invalid_token_response -An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: PKIX path building failed
I am trying to run spring-security-azuread from spring tutorials, i am able to run this in windows system as its spring boot application, but when i am trying to run in docker container from redhat openjdk, it fails with the below error.

Login with OAuth 2.0 [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while
attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error
on POST request for
"https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token":
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target

Code link
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-azuread
I am using redhat openjdk 17

FROM
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-17-runtime:1.20-2.1719294801

Docker file
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-17-runtime:1.20-2.1719294801
USER root
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/java /app/config
    && chgrp -R root /app /app/config
    && chmod -R 770 /app /app/config
    && chmod -R 777 /app/java 
COPY spring-security-azuread-3.2.1.jar /app/spring-security-azuread-3.2.1.jar
EXPOSE 9443
# Set a default command for debugging purposes
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/spring-security-azuread-3.2.1.jar"]

